# Powershell Remove first Line of CSV-File but keep CSV file format

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

Im retrieving data over an odbc.odbcconnection in Powershell.
After formating the data (cropping, replacing etc) i set the values for each retrieved line in a variable and out-file it to "file.csv" with -append.
Looks like this:

> ```
> $export= '"' + $var1 + '","' + $var2 + '","' ....
>
> $export | Out-File -Append -FilePath C:\Temp\file.csv
> ```

This gives me an CSV File with all the values from the ODBC-Query where every variable(value) is between 2 -> " (I need that for further processes)
If i now import that csv file to the next process i get an error with " Theres an Header-Line "
Which is correct because the the first dataline is the headerline.
If i remove the first line by hand and save the file, then upload it to the "process" it works fine. But i need it automated and not with an manuel "task".

What i have tried:
After saving the csv, do following:

> Import-CSV C:\Temp\file.csv -header XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX | export-csv C:\temp\newfile.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimeter ';'

But this sadly doesnt work, after upload this newfile.csv to the "process" i get an error that this is not an csv file.

So the question is, is there any other way to export my data as an csv without an header but still in the "csv" fileformat? Or what am i missing or doing wrong?

Comment: How about `Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\file.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 |  Out-File -FilePath C:\Temp\file_new.csv`

Comment: Or actually `$export  | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append -FilePath C:\Temp\file.csv`